# detecting bounding box in a form using java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I have the following  image

> [image]

So, i was trying to use tesseract to get hocr and then detect the bounding area of text to get the ends of the page. But, for the above image, even after the border rectangle there is some text which is making tesseract to detect the text and which in turn is not helping me to get the border rectangle coordinate.

What i am actually trying to do is to crop the image based on the border(outer rectangle).  Is there a way to get he coordinates of the outer rectangle using java. Also, if there are multiple rectangle's, is there a way to specifically get the bottom-right rectangle  corner. Is this possible to do using OpenCV ?

Comment: 1-Find all external contours. 2-Sort contours in descending order by contour area. 3-Pick the first contour and see if it's a polygon with exactly 4 vertices. 4-If it is then compute the bounding box of this contour. 5-Extract ROI based on this bounding box.

Comment: Region Of Interest. In your case the rectangle that you're trying to detect.